# Calling a win32 API and giving a callback to a class function

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to clean up some existing win32 UI code by putting it into a class. Previously I had an AppDlgProc function like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK AppDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { ... }
```

Which I used like so:

```
DialogBoxParam(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDD_SETTINGS, 0, AppDlgProc, 0);
```

Now I'm putting all this in a SettingsWindow object, and I call settingsWindow->show() which kicks off this:

```
void SettingsWindow::show(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
     DialogBoxParam(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDD_SETTINGS, 0, &SettingsWindow::AppDlgProc, 0);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm giving the callback method incorrectly here. Visual Studio tells me "Intellisense: Argument of type ... is incompatible with parameter of type DLGPROC". Googling seems to tell me seems to tell me [I need another argument](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks) - is there no other way?

For reference, my AppDlgProc function now looks like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK SettingsWindow::AppDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {  ... }
```

Comment: Raymond Chen wrote about this: [How can I make a callback function a member of my C++ class?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/27/10492898.aspx)

Comment: The calling conventions don't match, you can't just pass a non-static member function to a function that expects a `CALLBACK` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Window and dialog procedures (and other Win32 callback functions) need to be static or global functions - they can't be non-static class functions. Win32 is fundamentally a C-based API and it has no concept of the hidden `this` pointer that class functions require.

The normal way to do this is to declare the function as static and store a pointer to the class instance  in a window property. For example,

```
struct SettingsWindow
{
    // static wrapper that manages the "this" pointer
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK AppDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG)
            SetProp(hWnd, L"my_class_data", (HANDLE)lParam);
        else
        if (uMsg == WM_NCDESTROY)
            RemoveProp(hWnd, L"my_class_data");

        SettingsWindow* pThis = (SettingsWindow*)GetProp(hWnd, L"my_class_data");
        return pThis ? pThis->AppDlgFunc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) : FALSE;
    }

    INT_PTR AppDlgFunc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        // the real dialog procedure goes in here
    }
};


// to show the dialog - pass "this" as the dialog parameter
DialogBoxParam(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDD_SETTINGS, 0, SettingsWindow::AppDlgProc,
    (LPARAM)this);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I have a question though; what is the purpose of the if/else statement?

Comment: The `SetProp` docs say you have to remove the window property before the window is destroyed - presumably to avoid a memory leak, although I don't know if that is actually the case. In any event it's good practice to tidy up after yourself.