# How to put member functions as pointers to a WinAPI functions for registering them as WinAPI functions?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a class with member function that i want to pass to a WinAPI function as a pointer, so this function member would be registered as a WinAPI function.

But i cant do this, because my member function doesnt correspond to WinAPI declaration, because it implicitly contains additional 'this' parameter.

The only solution that i know is to define my member function as static.

But this is not good for me, because it will lately create badly implemented architecture of chain of static functions.

Are there better solutions?

Here is the example with a Windows Service:

```
class Test_service {
    std::wstring svc_name;
public:
    Test_service(const std::wstring& service_name);
    void serv_main_func(DWORD dwNumServicesArgs, LPWSTR* lpServiceArgsVectors);
};

Test_service::Test_service(const std::wstring& service_name): svc_name(service_name) {
    // there is error! only work if i declare serv_main_func as static
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY service_entry{ &svc_name[0], serv_main_func}; 
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(&service_entry);       
}

void Test_service::serv_main_func(DWORD dwNumServicesArgs, LPWSTR* lpServiceArgsVectors) {
    // DUMMY
}
```

Comment: Global or static is the only way. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678892/calling-a-win32-api-and-giving-a-callback-to-a-class-function

Comment: if global or static is the only way, then how people design OO-architecture using WinAPI functions?

Comment: It is merely a good example how a C api forces you to write correct C++ code.  A service process should implement a single service, your Test_service class should therefore be a singleton.

Comment: @hgrev Studying the source code of WTL would be a good idea for understanding oop with windows.

Comment: @hgrev - *how people design OO-architecture using WinAPI functions?* -- Mapping of static components to object instances (like MFC does), or global variables, or passing `this` as a parameter to the API function (if that is available), etc.  The bottom line is by hook or by crook, whatever means you come up with to track object instances to use, you use it.  There is no one single answer.

Comment: @hgrev Usually you make a static function that calls a non-static function. In this case I don't see how you could do it

Comment: @HansPassant singleton is the exact opposite of correct code

Comment: option 3: don't try to write object-oriented code

Comment: Register a static function that will call a std::function (or a vector of them) and initialize that std::function from a lambda. You can't register a lambda with capture directly, since a lambda with capture cannot be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: note that **most** WinAPI calls do have an extra void* where you can store the this pointer. This one doesn't, I guess because you can only register one service with the same function anyway.

Comment: It's not necessary to have only a single service in a process as Hans claimed, however it is necessary for each service to have its own entrypoint.  You can use class hierarchy to provide helper functions to make implementing the individual services easier; you can't have that class hierarchy provide the entry-points themselves.  There needs to be an orchestrator that knows about all the services and creates a single `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` array and performs the single call to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`.  The code in the question is wrong since it tries to do that per-service.

Comment: Because i want the service to self install.

Comment: For example, Borland's VCL wraps `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` in an OOP fashion. What they do is store the `TService` objects in a list, and then use a global function for `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`. It receives a service name and parameters, searches the list for a matching `TService` object with the same `Name`, and then calls that object's `TService.Main()` method. Each `TService` registers its own global function with `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()` to receive and route service messages to its `TService.Controller()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this where the API does not include a free parameter that can be used to hold `this`, I have found using libffi to create a function at runtime works well, though is admittedly a bit clunky.

This process involves using `ffi_closure_alloc()` to allocate a block of memory and then `ffi_prep_closure()` to actually write out the run-time created function. `ffi_prep_closure()` has the free parameter that can be used to hold `this`.

Instead of passing your own function's address, you pass what is written to the `binding` parameter to `ffi_closure_alloc()`.